# Solving differential equations by parametrization

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my book they solve the following two first-order differential equations by parametrization.

1) $x^4=y'^3-x^2y'$

2) $y=y'^2+2lny'$

Notice that there is no y in the first equation and no x in the second equation.
That's the signal that tells me to use parametrisation.

Now for the first one they use $t=\frac{y'}{x}$ and for the second one they use $ t = y' $.

How do I know which parametrization I should use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can solve the first equation for $$y'$$

Comment: for your second equation exists no closed form of a solution

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Did you read the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can know this by, well, trying some things out. A few straightforward things to try are either the substitutions:

$x =t, y = t, y/y' = t, y'/y = t$

Note that the first differential equation can be solved by substituting $z = y'$. The differential equation would become:

$$x^4 = z^3 - x^2z$$ which should be solved for $z$.

Sometimes you can use a geometrical argument. For example, when your differential equation is:

$$y'^2 + y^2 = 9$$

you can regognize the equation of a circle in the $y-y'$ plane and suggest the substitution:

$$\begin{cases} y' = 3\cos(t) \\y = 3 \sin(t)\end{cases}$$

Note that this way to solve this differential equation isn't probably the best way, but this was just to illustrate how to find a parametrisation.

Comment: Thanks, How should I recognize that my parametrization is a good one, I mean, imagine instead of $ t = \frac{y'}{x} $ I use $ t = y' $ I would get $ x^4= t^3-tx^2$. Whats wrong with this one?

Comment: You have to be able to solve for $x$, which is quite hard (here it would work if you use the substitution u = x^2, but your answer will involve roots and therefore I doubt whether you will reach any answer if you proceed this way)